error MSB4019: The imported project "D:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found
So I've seen several topic on the subject but so far could not find any clear answer as what the problem is, why it appeared and how to solve it.
I am not using npm, have Visual Studio 2022 installed, and am working on Rider.
Solution is as follow:

A C++ native project, name it A
A C++/CLI project, name it B, which has a dependency on A
A C# project, name it C, which has a dependency on B

B is located under D:\MyGitRepositories\MyRepository\B, under which we find the B.vcxproj file.
I'm simply trying to add an nuget package: dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json and get this error:

error MSB4019: The imported project "D:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props"
was not found. Confirm that the exp  ression in the Import declaration
"\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" is correct, and that the file exists on
disk.

It seems the issues lie in the VCTargetsPath variable, which seems empty. This variable is defined in MSBuild props. My guess is that it should be populated by the IDE once the project is started, providing it is targeting the correct MSBuild version. It seems it is not, and MSBuild is not in my PATH (which is not a surprise to me, since I have 4 different versions of it).
I already had this error in another project and managed to get it fixed by messing with Visual Studio Tools installation, the Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props somehow also appeared in the project folder. I could not reproduce here.
I could install my dependency using nuget install Newtonsoft.Json but it created a folder with the dependency within the project A and this dependency is now commited and added the the repository. Which I do not really like and I do not think this is how it should be done.
The files can be found under the BuildTools and Visual Studio MSBuild installation folder (under ProgramFiles and ProgramFiles(x86). I have 4 installations of it under the official folders.
How to fix this ?
Edit: How to reproduce:

With VS or Rider, create a C# console project.
Add a C++/CLI console project to the solution
Add the C++/CLI project as a dependency to the C# console project
Using the terminal, under the C# console project root, run nuget add package <anypackage>


Is there any un-production code that can be shared(which is able to reproduce the issue)? :)

No but I can give steps, I'll edit the topic

I think the issue comes from the dependencies are not compatible, you can take a look of my answer. :)

I am able to reproduce your situation:

I think you are using 'dotnet add package ', right? Because I didn't find the command you mentioned:
Install package with Nuget CLI
Please notice 'dotnet add package' is only support .NET Core 3.1 SDK and later versions:
dotnet add package


And I am able to make the issue disappear:

I am using these apps:

﻿CLR class library(.NET) is C++ project that has no starting files and targets .NET. Provides interoperability between .NET and C++ code.
